# Erlang-Pid control

Tags: erlang, pid-controller

I have written a simple chat server in Erlang (without any sockets or ports, just between to message among multiple shells), but when I try to simulate it I have some problems. 
Almost every client function (like pm, say_to_all) in my implementation needs Chat_server-s Process ID.
If I open chat_server and client in one shell, I can easily bound chat_server's process ID and access it if necessary, but problem comes up when I want to open another shell for client.
look at the picture --> http://s018.radikal.ru/i501/1308/ee/a194aa8486ae.png
how to access the process from 1-st shell (chat_server)  from second shell  (chat_client) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could register your server globally under a certain name (http://erlang.org/doc/man/global.html#register_name-2). That way it would be possible for you to access the server from any shell within your chatsystem.

Don't forget, that you need to connect the shells with net_adm:ping first, to let the shells know of globally registered names.

And I can really recommend looking into gen_server (http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html) since it can really help when trying to organize a client-server-structure.

Edit:
Sorry maybe you also want an explanation for your problem.
This is because every erlang-shell has its own environment with own variables etc. That means a second shell does not know about any variables of other shells.

Comment: thanks a lot. erlang global module helped me very much, now my code works :)

Comment: Glad I could be of help.